# How do I make corners angled like this using css?

Tags: css

Here is an image of what I'm talking about:

[image: corners]

Is there a way to get the corners like this using css3 or do I have to resort to images? I believe I saw a tutorial on this somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't rounded corners that just look straight because the amount of rounding is so small?

Comment: If the amount of rounding was *that* small, you wouldn't see anything

Answer (score 15):

Do you mean something like **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/k86Mr/1/)**?

[image: Angled corners]

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="like"></div>
        <h3>User927</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="foot">
        <a href="">More</a>
    </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 310px;
    position: relative;
}
.head {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.cont {
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
.foot {
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
.head:before,
.head:after,
.foot:before,
.foot:after {
    font-size: 0px; 
    content: ".";
    position: absolute;    
}
.head:before {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.head:after {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.foot:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid white;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.foot:after {
    border-bottom: 7px solid white;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Downside: for IE7 you would need extra span's in the markup because the `:after` and `:before` specifiers are not supported, see [this revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/k86Mr/2/).

Answer (score 2):

I've had great luck with jQuery Corners:

http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/

It can do slanted corners as well as many other varieties, and works well in older browsers too:

Answer (score 1):

You can do *rounded* corners (such as on the 28/like in the image) with CSS, but corners cut like those at the top of the container require images.

Comment: well technically you could do cut corners like this in a similar way to one of the old rounded corner hacks (lots of small layered divs), but I'd hate to send anyone down that road.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't afraid of CSS3, then dive into either [border-images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-border-image) or [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/background-image).  It's both css and images.

Answer (score 1):

[IMPORTANT] Go for this approach if you really want to stick to CSS 2.0.

It may seem weird, but I have seen this in Google rendered pages! (that was for rounding but the same technique can be used here):

```
.border-line {background:blue; border:solid 3px gray; border-width: 0 3px; height:1px;}

<div class='top-border-line'></div>
<div class='border-line' style='margin:0 5px;'></div>
<div class='border-line' style='margin:0 4px;'></div>
<div class='border-line' style='margin:0 3px;'></div>
<div class='border-line' style='margin:0 2px;'></div>
<div class='border-line' style='margin:0 1px;'></div>
```

Got the idea? each of those divs are one single row steping backward linearly to form the "angle". and there is a top solid line above them.

Answer (score 0):

[This javascript library](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js)

Cross browser simplicity! Why use CSS anyway...