# CSS border shape - how to cut off rectangle right upper corner

Tags: css

I just wondering is there way to make a tab like shape border? 
To be more clear I am to draw the shape in asterisks. I mean this border shape.

```
*********************
***********************
*************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
```

For this how in CSS cut off the rectangle right upper corner? Or what is a more optimal way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make angled tab like this using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895273/how-to-make-angled-tab-like-this-using-css) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474168/how-do-i-make-corners-angled-like-this-using-css

Comment: No, I am looking a way of making non-rounded tab shape

Comment: I think the "triangles" part of the duplicate is your answer.

Comment: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/ Found a great plugin I will leave it here for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use borders to achieve something like that. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/Q5NrB/1/) Maybe not the best answer but a start point if you insist on pure css.

Edit: Updated **[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/9qAVF/)** here

**Markup**

```
<div>
<div class="wrapper inner">
    <div class="abc"></div>
    <div class="container">I AM A TAB<div>
</div>
<div class="border inner">
    <div class="ab"></div>
    <div class="bcontainer"><div>
</div>
</div>
```

​

**CSS**

```
.inner{position:fixed;}


.border{width:72px;height:52px;z-index:-1;top:0px;}


.wrapper{width:70px;top:1px;left:1px;}


.container {background:rgb(226,226,226);text-align:center;}

.bcontainer{background:black;width:71px;height:41px;}
.abc {
    width: 60px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(226,226,226);
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.ab{    width: 61px;
    border-bottom: 11px solid black;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;}​
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS does not support any non-square, non-rounded border shapes. You can use a bunch of DIVs with stepped widths or an image, but CSS alone can't really help.

Alternately, you can try overlaying some [CSS triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), but that's a bit of a hack.

Comment: The Dupe has the complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895273/how-to-make-angled-tab-like-this-using-css

Comment: You mean rounded corner + triangle? But how to avoid using rounded corner? I am not pretty sure how to combine shapes in this case :S

Comment: You need to add a DIV that contains the triangle, then absolutey position it over the corner of your tab.

Comment: I see, but what about the bottom? I need somehow to add another rectangle right under the triangle or something?

Answer (score 2):

Using `border-corner-shape` css attribute could have done the trick... if it was implemented in CSS3! It's proposed in CSS4 draft though - yeah no kidding!

Implementation is uncertain however and need support. Read:
http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/border-corner-shape-is-in-danger-and-you-can-help/

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't get the http://lea.verou.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/bevel-4.png ... What the two images mean? I mean one css and two images? Could you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

If that corner can be rounded, `border-radius` is probably all you need: http://border-radius.com/

If the corner has to be at an angle, you're not likely to get that without some pretty messy HTML. There is no standard property that would do it. The best alternative is to make that particular part of the border an image and then use `background-image` and `background-position` to place it in the upper corner.

Comment: Background-image for the right upper corner? But how to make its scale dynamic then? I mean it demands some absolute position or something?

Comment: There's no need for absolute positioning; simply use percentages to position the content.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS3 `border-radius` property : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-radius))

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a sharp corner, not a rounded one.

Comment: @j08691 I know but like others said, sharp corner can't be really done in CSS... I suggested an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but it tricky and non-standard.